# Extract the content from Wikipedia JSON file

Tags: php, json

I am getting the content of "Sullivan County, Pennsylvania" in json format from wikipedia by following api url https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Sullivan_County,_Pennsylvania&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json

Now i want to display the content in well HTML format or similar like wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sullivan_County,_Pennsylvania

I am beginner in JSON, how can extract the content in well HTML format?

Comment: JSON is just a format; what programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP language

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to fetch the data using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and then [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the response to transform into a PHP variable. Then you can echo out the fields you need. A very simple example would be something like this:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Sullivan_County,_Pennsylvania&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json');
$data = json_decode($response, true);
?>

<h1><?php echo $data['query']['pages']['91928']['title']; ?></h1>
```